# Insertar un elemento en una posicion de una lista C++11

Tags: lista, c++11, array, eficiencia

Necesito insertar un elemento dentro de una lista declarada de la siguiente forma:

```
list < list <unsigned int> > bucket (16);
```

Debo insertar un elemento dentro de una de las listas de bucket de la forma más eficiente posible. Tengo la posición en la cual debo insertar dicho valor, pero no se me ocurre la mejor forma de insertarlo (preferiblemente, se debería evitar insert).

Mi código actual usa, en lugar de `list< list <unsigned int> > bucket (16);`, `vector< list <unsigned int> > bucket (16);`, siendo este el siguiente:

```
void LSDRadixSortList (list<unsigned int> &v, int m)
{
    int logaritmo = (log10(m))/(log10(16));
    vector< list <unsigned int> > bucket (16);

    for (int i = 0; i <= logaritmo; ++i)
    {

        for (auto buck : bucket){
            buck.clear();
        }

        for_each(v.begin(), 
            next(v.begin(),v.size()),
            [i,&bucket](unsigned int x){

                int digit = x;

                int mult = 0xF;
                mult <<= 4 * i;

                digit = digit & mult;

                digit >>= 4 * i;

                bucket.at(digit).push_back(x); ///< Esta es la linea a mejorar
            });
        v.clear();

        for (auto buck : bucket){
            v.splice(v.end(), move(buck));
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito algo que equivalga a `bucket.at(digit).push_back(x);` para listas y sin ser tan costoso (por lo que se, las listas suelen funcionar mejor que los vectores).

Comment: ¿La inserción siempre es al final de la lista anidada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> preferiblemente, se debería evitar insert

No veo el motivo para evitar el uso de `insert`... saaaaalvo que estés trabajando con `vector` ¿Por qué?

`std::vector` es un tipo de contenedor en el que los elementos ocupan posiciones de memoria contiguas. Así, si suponemos que cada elemento ocupa únicamente un byte y que la lista tiene 3 elementos (A,B,C) éstos se encontrarían así:

```
Posición de memoria aleatoria
vvvv
0xA0 0xA1 0xA2
  A    B    C
```

Si ahora deseases insertar un elemento en la segunda posición tendrías que desplazar los elementos 2 y 3 para poder hacer hueco al nuevo elemento:

```
0xA0 0xA1 0xA2 0xA3
  A    D    B    C
```

El coste de esta operación es dependiente del número de elementos a mover.

Ahora bien, si en vez de un contenedor tipo `std::vector`, usas `std::list` la cosa cambia. ¿Por qué? Básicamente porque `std::list` implementa una lista doblemente enlazada. En una lista enlazada el coste de insertar un elemento (una vez localizada la ubicación) es constante, ya que únicamente hay que reajustar punteros... de hecho la [documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) ya lo deja claro:

> std::list is a container that supports constant time insertion and removal of elements from anywhere in the container.

Ahora bien, el problema de una lista enlazada es que cada elemento se encuentra en una posición aleatoria de la memoria... para llegar a una posición antes tienes que pasar por todos los nodos anteriores (o posteriores si estás retrocediendo)... en este caso el coste de la operación dependerá de lo rápido que consigas llegar al punto de inserción. Así que, resumiendo:

- `std::vector` permite iterar rápidamente por sus elementos pero penaliza las inserciones
- `std::list` permite inserciones rápidas pero penaliza las búsquedas

Así que ya ves que `insert` no es ningún demonio... si una operación tarda demasiado tal vez sea porque estás usando los contenedores incorrectos (o los estás usando mal).